# Using "&" and "|" in SSHPass script

Tags: terminal, unix, ssh

I am making a script for my parents on their Mac's so that they can SSH into my Linux computer, and send commands, create popups etc.

This is one of my commands:

```
sshpass -p Password ssh maliciouzzhd@10.0.0.1 export DISPLAY=:0 & mate-session-save --force-logout
```

My problem is that the Mac treats the "&" as not in the sshpass script, and executes the argument after using the Mac terminal, no SSH.

So

```
sshpass -p Password ssh maliciouzzhd@10.0.0.1 export DISPLAY=:0 & mate-session-save --force-logout
```

would execute

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

in the SSH session, but

```
mate-session-save --force-logout
```

would be executed in the Mac terminal.

If anyone could help me out with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH accepts single argument as a command, not multiple ones, so the command line should look like this (note the quotes):

```
sshpass -p Password ssh maliciouzzhd@10.0.0.1 "export DISPLAY=:0 & mate-session-save --force-logout"
```

But the general idea might not work, because you didn't allow X11 forwarding (add `-Y` switch to the `ssh`).

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it is now saying `Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused`

Comment: Do you have X server installed on your mac?

Comment: How do I check? I'm not use to Mac, its my parents

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341 -- you need to install XQuartz manually

Comment: Wait... I am trying to control my Linux laptop through SSH from my Mac, do I need XQuartz on my Mac too? My Linux definitely has XServer stuff on it.

Comment: Yes, you need X server on the mac, if you want to show windows from your Linux system.